# An error message in R telling that it cannot allocate a memory of some size

Tags: r

In a simulation program of a simulation size of 500 the following error message in the picture is shown:

[image]

I have read in the web that a 32-bit machine may have this problem. Now, this is also giving me some outputs. My question is that, is the calculation properly going inside the loop but R cannot display it? Or that the calculation itself is not actually working inside the loop?

If the calculation is going properly within the loop but R cannot just display the results I may leave bothering about this. Can anyone tell me?

**EDIT:**
My inexperience in R (in fact in any programming language is making some difficulty and I am sorry for that). Here is my full code as you wanted to see in the comments. Since this is a very long code, so I thought you would not like to see it!

```
sink("kopaltaikharap.txt")

###Hypothesis Testing: Under Null for Model A

size=500

WLR<-rep(0,size)    #vector of standardized test statistics

count.WLR<-rep(0,size)

##for NLR test:

NLR<-rep(0,size)    #vector of standardized test statistics

count.NLR<-rep(0,size)

for(j in 1:size){   #loop j begins

##############################################################################
##Data Generation:

n<-300 #total patients

x<-rbinom(n,1,0.5) #Indicator of treatment A. 

r<-rbinom(n,1,0.5)

#Generating t0 from exponential with mean 1.5 years:

t0<-rep(0,n)
for(i in 1:n){
t0[i]<-ifelse(r[i]==0,rexp(1,1/1.5),0)
}

#Generating tr from exponential with mean 0.5 year:

tr<-rep(0,n)
for(i in 1:n){
tr[i]<-ifelse(r[i]==1,rexp(1,1/0.5),0)
}

#Generating B treatment indicator:

z<-rbinom(n,1,0.5)  

#Generating ts (time after remission) from exponential with mean 2.5 and 1.5 years:

ts<-rep(0,n)
for(i in 1:n){
ts[i]<-ifelse(z[i]==1,rexp(1,1/2.5),rexp(1,1/1.5))
}

#Generating survival time t(i):

t<-rep(0,n)
for(i in 1:n){
t[i]<-(1-r[i])*t0[i]+r[i]*(tr[i]+ts[i])
}

d<-data.frame(x,r,t0,tr,z,ts,t)
d

# As no censoring is mentioned in model A, so cenc is set equal to (max(d$t)+1).

d$cenc<-rep((max(d$t)+1),n) #so that u(i)=min(t(i),cenc(i))=t(i) and censoring has no effect.

d$delta<-rep(0,n)
for(i in 1:n){
d$delta[i]<-ifelse(d$t[i]<d$cenc[i],1,0)
}

d$u<-rep(0,n)
for(i in 1:n){
d$u[i]<-min(d$t[i],d$cenc[i])
}

p1<-sum(d$z*d$r*(d$tr<d$cenc)*(d$x==1))/sum(d$r*(d$tr<d$cenc)*(d$x==1))
p1
p2<-sum(d$z*d$r*(d$tr<d$cenc)*(d$x==0))/sum(d$r*(d$tr<d$cenc)*(d$x==0))
p2

d<-d[order(d$u),]
d   #data frame sorted by u.

#taking unique u's.

du<-unique(d$u)

##############################################################################



##############################################################################
##Test Statistic:

#we define indices i for d and k for du.

zn.wlr<-rep(0,length(du))

K.hat<-rep(0,length(du))

Q1<-rep(0,length(du))
Q2<-rep(0,length(du))

sum.wt1dn1<-rep(0,length(du))
sum.wt2dn2<-rep(0,length(du))
sum.wt1y1<-rep(0,length(du))
sum.wt2y2<-rep(0,length(du))

sum.dn1<-rep(0,length(du))
sum.dn2<-rep(0,length(du))
sum.y1<-rep(0,length(du))
sum.y2<-rep(0,length(du))

lambda.hat<-rep(0,length(du))

q1<-rep(0,length(du))
q2<-rep(0,length(du))


##for NLR test:

zn.nlr<-rep(0,length(du))

q4var.nlr<-rep(0,length(du))

sum.dn11<-rep(0,length(du))
sum.dn21<-rep(0,length(du))
sum.y11<-rep(0,length(du))
sum.y21<-rep(0,length(du))


for(k in 1:length(du)){ #loop k (for each death time point) begins

wt1<-rep(0,n)
wt2<-rep(0,n)
dn1<-rep(0,n)
dn2<-rep(0,n)
y1<-rep(0,n)
y2<-rep(0,n)



##for NLR test:

dn11<-rep(0,n)
dn21<-rep(0,n)
y11<-rep(0,n)
y21<-rep(0,n)


for(i in 1:n){  #loop i (for each individual) begins

wt1[i]<-(1-d$r[i]*(d$tr[i]<=du[k])+d$r[i]*(d$tr[i]<=du[k])*d$z[i]/p1)*(d$x[i]==1)

wt2[i]<-(1-d$r[i]*(d$tr[i]<=du[k])+d$r[i]*(d$tr[i]<=du[k])*d$z[i]/p2)*(d$x[i]==0)

y1[i]<-(d$u[i]>=du[k])*(d$x[i]==1)

y2[i]<-(d$u[i]>=du[k])*(d$x[i]==0)

dn1[i]<-(d$u[i]==du[k])*d$delta[i]*(d$x[i]==1)

dn2[i]<-(d$u[i]==du[k])*d$delta[i]*(d$x[i]==0)

sum.wt1dn1[k]<-sum.wt1dn1[k]+wt1[i]*dn1[i]

sum.wt2dn2[k]<-sum.wt2dn2[k]+wt2[i]*dn2[i]

sum.wt1y1[k]<-sum.wt1y1[k]+wt1[i]*y1[i]

sum.wt2y2[k]<-sum.wt2y2[k]+wt2[i]*y2[i]

sum.dn1[k]<-sum.dn1[k]+dn1[i]

sum.dn2[k]<-sum.dn2[k]+dn2[i]

sum.y1[k]<-sum.y1[k]+y1[i]

sum.y2[k]<-sum.y2[k]+y2[i]


##if(y1[i]==0 & y2[i]==0) lambda.hat[k]<-0 else lambda.hat[k]<-(dn1[i]+dn2[i])/(y1[i]+y2[i])    

##this is actually h(u_k) hat (estimated hazard function, not cumulative hazard).


##for NLR test:

dn11[i]<-(d$u[i]==du[k])*d$delta[i]*(d$x[i]==1)*(d$z[i]==1)

dn21[i]<-(d$u[i]==du[k])*d$delta[i]*(d$x[i]==0)*(d$z[i]==1)

y11[i]<-(d$u[i]>=du[k])*(d$x[i]==1)*(d$z[i]==1)

y21[i]<-(d$u[i]>=du[k])*(d$x[i]==0)*(d$z[i]==1)

sum.dn11[k]<-sum.dn11[k]+dn11[i]

sum.dn21[k]<-sum.dn21[k]+dn21[i]

sum.y11[k]<-sum.y11[k]+y11[i]

sum.y21[k]<-sum.y21[k]+y21[i]

}   #loop i ends.

if(sum.wt1y1[k]==0 & sum.wt2y2[k]==0) zn.wlr[k]<-0 else zn.wlr[k]<-(sum.wt1dn1[k]*sum.wt2y2[k]-sum.wt2dn2[k]*sum.wt1y1[k])/(sum.wt1y1[k]+sum.wt2y2[k])

# "|" is the "or" operator. 

if(sum.wt1y1[k]==0 & sum.wt2y2[k]==0) K.hat[k]<-0 else K.hat[k]<-sum.wt2y2[k]/(sum.wt1y1[k]+sum.wt2y2[k])

if(sum.y1[k]==0 & sum.y2[k]==0) lambda.hat[k]<-0 else lambda.hat[k]<-(sum.dn1[k]+sum.dn2[k])/(sum.y1[k]+sum.y2[k])  



wt1<-rep(0,n)
wt2<-rep(0,n)
dn1<-rep(0,n)
dn2<-rep(0,n)
y1<-rep(0,n)
y2<-rep(0,n)

for(i in 1:n){  #loop i (for each individual) begins

wt1[i]<-(1-d$r[i]*(d$tr[i]<=du[k])+d$r[i]*(d$tr[i]<=du[k])*d$z[i]/p1)*(d$x[i]==1)

wt2[i]<-(1-d$r[i]*(d$tr[i]<=du[k])+d$r[i]*(d$tr[i]<=du[k])*d$z[i]/p2)*(d$x[i]==0)

y1[i]<-(d$u[i]>=du[k])*(d$x[i]==1)

y2[i]<-(d$u[i]>=du[k])*(d$x[i]==0)

dn1[i]<-(d$u[i]==du[k])*d$delta[i]*(d$x[i]==1)

dn2[i]<-(d$u[i]==du[k])*d$delta[i]*(d$x[i]==0)


q1[k]<-q1[k]+wt1[i]*(dn1[i]-lambda.hat[k]*y1[i])

q2[k]<-q2[k]+wt2[i]*(dn2[i]-lambda.hat[k]*y2[i])


}   #loop i ends.



Q1[k]<-K.hat[k]*q1[k]

Q2[k]<-(1-K.hat[k])*q2[k]


##for NLR test:

if(sum.y11[k]==0 & sum.y21[k]==0) zn.nlr[k]<-0 else zn.nlr[k]<-(sum.dn11[k]*sum.y21[k]-sum.dn21[k]*sum.y11[k])/(sum.y11[k]+sum.y21[k])

if(sum.y11[k]==0 & sum.y21[k]==0) q4var.nlr[k]<-0 else q4var.nlr[k]<-(sum.y11[k]*sum.y21[k]/(sum.y11[k]+sum.y21[k]))*((sum.dn11[k]+sum.dn21[k])/(sum.y11[k]+sum.y21[k]))


}   #loop k ends.

Zn.WLR<-sum(zn.wlr)

sigmasq.hat.WLR<-mean((Q1)^2)+mean((Q2)^2)

WLR[j]<-(n^(-0.5)*Zn.WLR)/sqrt(sigmasq.hat.WLR)

#count.WLR[j]<-ifelse(WLR[j]>=-1.96 & WLR[j]<1.96,0,1)

count.WLR[j]<-ifelse(abs(WLR[j])>1.96,1,0)

##for NLR test:

Zn.NLR<-sum(zn.nlr)

sigmasq.hat.NLR<-n^(-1)*sum(q4var.nlr)

NLR[j]<-(n^(-0.5)*Zn.NLR)/sqrt(sigmasq.hat.NLR)

#count.NLR[j]<-ifelse(NLR[j]>=-1.96 & NLR[j]<1.96,0,1)

count.NLR[j]<-ifelse(abs(NLR[j])>1.96,1,0)

}   #loop j ends.

meanWLR<-mean(WLR)  #sample mean of the normalized test statistic
meanWLR
RR.WLR<-sum(count.WLR)/size
RR.WLR
meanNLR<-mean(NLR)  #sample mean of the normalized test statistic
meanNLR
RR.NLR<-sum(count.NLR)/size
RR.NLR


sink()

##sometimes shows this message:

#Error in if (sum.wt1y1 == 0 | sum.wt2y2 == 0) zn[k] <- 0 else zn[k] <- (sum.wt1y1 *  : 
#  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

# count.WLR and count.NLR always come 0, 0, 0,..., 0. Is it okay?
```

Comment: What's the whole code you're using?

Comment: You run basically out of memory - try to check your loop if you create useless objects that consume memory and if you can reduce the amount of required memory of the loop. But as Roman said, without seeing the code it's hard to give any further hint.

Comment: I have given the codes. As this is a long code so I thought it would irritate people if I write them here! Sorry for that!!

Comment: Can anyone tell me exactly where the problem is occurring? I am really frustrated with it. :(

Answer (score 2):

You need to be asking yourself why a small simulation would create a 300MB vector. (It's not particularly meaningful to say that a "simulation is of size 500".) You are also running multiple instances of R. Each instance will be competing for continguous RAM. You are also requesting that we all load the "mind.reading" package and only a few of us have gotten it to compile properly.

Comment: I am sorry @DWin. If you want you can see my codes and suggest me where I should think differently. Although it is tough for you to see and understand my purpose, but you may see where such a big vector is being created. I am too inexperienced in R. So, I beg your pardon for this.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly where the problem is occurring? I am really frustrated with it. :(

Comment: No I cannot. The code runs. It does not complete in a sensible amount of time and it appears horribly inefficient by virtue of calculating the same vectors over and over again. Limiting to size=5 and n=30 It runs in acceptable time although it produces NaN and NA results for some of the output. The size of the output does not seem to scale up as "size" increases and your code is not sufficiently commented for me to know if this is intended. But it does not seem to have an explosive memory growth. Your problem seems to be limited machine resources. Use standard debugging methods.

Comment: I will add that after using a reduced size run of this code that every object created ends up as length 1 and class "character", so I think you have done something weird with your assignments that coerce things to the wrong class. You really need to build up slow and test subsections of your code to make sure they are performing properly.

Comment: The reason of the NaN or NA is occurring for small n. n should be made large to avoid zero observation from a particular group. When there is no observation from a group, then the denominator of a quantity becomes zero. n=100 should be fine. I detected that in my computer 487 times it runs properly but the other 13 observations are zero with this error message.